# Entity Framework - Custom Field that get data from another Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have this scenario:

```
public class Source
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceMembership> InvoiceMemberships { get; set;}
}

public class InvoiceMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Source source { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTemplate InvoiceTemplate { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceTemplate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPayment { get; set; }
}
```

How can i have a field named `CurrentTemplate` with type of `InvoiceTemplate` in `Source` Entity That have `EndDate=null` in related `InvoiceMembership` row?
EDIT:
i use bellow code, but it's not really true way!

```
[NotMapped]
    public InvoiceTemplate CurrentTemplate { get {
        var context=new MedicalContext();
        var template = context.InvoiceMemberships.Where(m => m.source == this).Where(m => m.EndDate == null).Select(m => m.InvoiceTemplate);
        if (template != null)
            return (InvoiceTemplate)template;
        else
            return null;
    } }
```

Comment: Does it need to be in the database or you simply want a calculated field based on what is in invoicememberships ? In that case just create a member and decorate it with [NotMapped]

Comment: i edit my Post @PhilipStuyck...i don't need it in DataBase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but with EF computed properties are such a hassle.

Let's say you have:

```
public class Source
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public InvoiceTemplate CurrentTemplate
    { 
        get
        {
            return InvoiceMemberships
                   .Where(i = i.EndDate == null)
                   .Select(i => i.InvoiceTemplate)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceMembership> InvoiceMemberships { get; set;}
}
```

There just too many conditions (in my opinion) that should be met to make this work:

- `CurrentTemplate` can't be used directly in a LINQ query: EF will complain that the expression can't be translated into SQL.
- You always have to `Include()` `InvoiceMemberships.InvoiceTemplate` to be able to access `CurrentTemplate` in memory, after the context is disposed. This will always load *all* `InvoiceMemberships` + `InvoiceTemplate` for each `Source` object (in one query).
- Without using `Include()` you can only access `CurrentTemplate` before the context is disposed. This will trigger lazy loading of *all* `InvoiceMemberships` + `InvoiceTemplate` for each `Source` object  in separate queries.

As you see, you'll always load (much) more data than needed to get only one `InvoiceMembership` per `Source`.

The most efficient way is to query the required data into a projection, so the predicate `EndDate == null` can be included in the SQL query.

We'll have to wait for NHibernate-style formula properties.

Comment: thanks @Gert Arnold ... i have another question,if i want to delete navigation to `InvoiceMembership` in `Source` Entity so how can i get `CurrentTemplate`?

Comment: @Mahdi It's better to ask a new question if new issues arise. At StackOverflow we don't create threads as most forums do.

Comment: How can we reference this NotMapped field in DTO? 

`public InvoiceTemplate CurrentTemplate { get; }`

is that right way?

Answer (score 0):

Expose your Foreign Key value directly in your `InvoiceMembership` POCO (it must be there in the database anyway if the relation exists), and the entire query will be elegantly converted to SQL directly by L2E:

```
public class InvoiceMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SourceId")]
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTemplate InvoiceTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

And in `Source`:

```
[NotMapped]
public InvoiceTemplate CurrentTemplate
{
    get
    {
        using (var context = new MedicalContext())
            return context.InvoiceMemberships
                          .Where(m => m.SourceId == this.ID)
                          .Where(m => m.EndDate == null)
                          .Select(m => m.InvoiceTemplate)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

However, this has the drawback that - each time the property is accessed - the database will be queried. It might be best to move this method to the `InvoiceMembership` class, where you know your `InvoiceMembership` objects are getting loaded anyway, and make it a method:

```
public class InvoiceMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SourceId")]
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoiceTemplate InvoiceTemplate { get; set; }

    static public InvoiceTemplate ReadCurrentTemplate(int sourceId)
    {
        using (var context = new MedicalContext())
            return context.InvoiceMemberships
                          .Where(m => m.SourceId == sourceId)
                          .Where(m => m.EndDate == null)
                          .Select(m => m.InvoiceTemplate)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So, now, you have a *method*, not a property, to no longer hide the fact that an action is being taken each time you access it ... the name *Read*CurrentTemplate tells you that. And why not make it `static` now? Furthermore, making it `static` means you no longer have to worry about `NotMappedAttribute`.

But we'd still like to have access in `Source`, wouldn't we (especially if dropping the `ICollection<InvoiceMembership>` navigation property, as I see in your comments you wish to do)? This is now no longer an EF concern at all, but a regular, lazy-loading (if you wish it to be), concern in the `Source` class:

```
readonly Lazy<InvoiceTemplate> _currentTemplate;
public Source()
{
    _currentTemplate = new Lazy<InvoiceTemplate>(t => t = InvoiceMembership.ReadCurrentTemplate(ID));
}
[NotMapped]
public InvoiceTemplate CurrentTemplate
{
    get { return _currentTemplate.Value; }
}
```

So, doing this, you're still going to take the hit of running the database query to get the value of `CurrentTemplate`, but only *once* to evaluate the `Lazy` private backer; afterward, for the life of this `Source` object, this property will be the same as the first time it was read. This seemed to fit the model of how you were going to use it, considering it was only ever a read-only property in your examples. And it would only be for the life of the `Source` object, which should be in a context anyway.

If not, this should be method `ReadCurrentTemplate` (non-`static`, no parameter) on `Source` as well, and simply return `InvoiceMembership.ReadCurrentTemplate(ID)` directly, to indicate that each time it's called it's reading from the Database.